# How can I keep Ubuntu from dropping my network connection when it goes to sleep/hibernate mode?

Tags: networking, sleep

I have my computer running a Minecraft server as well as sshd (so I can sign in and check on things), but if I leave my computer on for about a day it goes into sleep then eventually hibernation mode and drops my network connection, rendering the servers useless. Is there any way I can change it so that it doesn't drop the connection when it goes to sleep or hibernates, or just doesn't hibernate or sleep?

I am not running Ubuntu-server, just the desktop version (10.04).

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to not drop the network connection when you switch off the computer. It is easy to configure it not to suspend and hibernate though. It's been a little while since I used 10.04, but somewhere in the System menu, you'll find something called power management. There you can choose when or if it should suspend or hibernate.

Comment: I have the setting telling it to never go to sleep, (but to shut down the monitor after a certain time), it still does it.

Comment: @ajtgarber The Power Management dialog in 10.04 looks similar to [this one](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-IBcfDqcp7vY/Tk800LrIZJI/AAAAAAAACac/bxUJQGjilvs/s1600/power+management+window.png). Did you use this to disable sleep+hibernate. If it still goes to sleep, this is a bug. After which time does this happen? (My laptop with 10.04 never goes to sleep when on AC as configured.)